# Correcting misunderstandings from Google's Speech2Text service

Tags: optimization, google-api, search-engine, speech-to-text

I am using Google's Speech2Text API and would like to optimize the results I get, correcting misunderstood words by performing Google searches to find possible phrases within a chosen topic. Is there a service I can use for that?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think there is a service like that already in existence. But it wouldn't be too much work to write one.

You're already using Google's API to perform the speech recognition, so presumably you'd be comfortable using it to perform a search for the "chosen topic".

Once you've done that you can take all the answer pages and concatenate them together to make a corpus of phrases that match the chosen topic. From those you can implement an algorithm to find the closest possible substring ([try these](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=closest%20substring%20algorithm)). You're looking for the substring of that whole corpus that is closest to the speech recognition results you got from Google. That should give you your answer.